# Long time for making negative photo

Tags: c#, graphics

This method takes a long time to process compared to common picture editors ,why is that?

```
public Image InvertColor(Image img)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img);

        for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
            {
                bmp.SetPixel(i, j,
                    Color.FromArgb(
                    byte.MaxValue - bmp.GetPixel(i, j).R,
                    byte.MaxValue - bmp.GetPixel(i, j).G,
                    byte.MaxValue - bmp.GetPixel(i, j).B));
            }
        }
        return (Image)bmp;
    }
```

Comment: Because SetPixel is extremely slow.

Comment: If you used a variable to store the result of get pixel rather than calling it 3 separate times?

Comment: Look at [this post in Bob Powell's blog](http://bobpowell.net/negativeimage.aspx), which shows you __exactly__ what you ask for! For other image manipulation code, do learn how to use `LockBits` and your code will be a match for regular image processing applications!!

Comment: See my answer and (in this case only) forget Bob..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fast way to do it. It uses a `ColorMatrix` and takes basically no time at all, even for large `Images`.

```
private Image fastInvert(Image img)
{
    float[][] cm = new float[][]
    {
        new float[] {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, -1, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 0, -1, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        new float[] {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}
    };

    ColorMatrix CM = new ColorMatrix(cm);
    ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();
    ia.SetColorMatrix(CM);
    using ( Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img) )

        g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), 0, 0,
            img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);

    return img;
      
}
```

The matrix data are kudos to [Visual Kicks](http://www.vcskicks.com/image-invert.php), who get it right, as opposed to any other site I found, including [Bob Powell's](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230042200/http://bobpowell.net/negativeimage.aspx), whose update really is a hack and didn't even work for me..

Comment: Thanks a lot . it's very fast like Photoshop :-)  I think your answer is the best . thank you again

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` methods are slow. Not very slow, but because you are doing so many calls, the overhead adds up.

You can start with only calling `GetPixel` once for each pixel instead of three times:

```
public Image InvertColor(Image img) {
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img);
  for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++) {
       Color source = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);
       bmp.SetPixel(i, j,
         Color.FromArgb(
           byte.MaxValue - source.R,
           byte.MaxValue - source.G,
           byte.MaxValue - source.B
         )
       );
    }
  }
  return (Image)bmp;
}
```

That should make it about twice as fast. To get it faster you need to access the image data directly. You can use the [`LockBits` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a pointer to the image data.

Comment: it doesn't work =>   bmp.SetPixel(i, j,
       Color source = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);

Comment: @Mojtaba: Sorry, I put that code in the wrong place. I edited it right after posting it.

Comment: Thank you so much it seems faster